# react-native switch between two navigation components

Tags: react-native, react-redux, architecture, react-native-navigation

I want to implement two types of navigations and switch between them. I got 5 pages in total.

For the first visit, the user should go from page 1 to 5 in a unidirectional flow.

For the second visit, the user should see the bottom navigation that allows him to access all 5 pages. How would one implement such switch best? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you create a `Tab Navigator` and `Stack Navigator`, and then toggle them according to a state variable?

Comment: thanks! that's what I ended up doing now so far it seems to work :)